# How can I take a picture with my iSight camera?

Tags: macos, camera

I have a MacBook Air which has a built in camera. Is there any simple application (preferably one that comes with Mac OS X) which simply takes a picture and saves it as PNG or JPG?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, the application is called "Photo Booth," and lives, I'm pretty sure, in /Applications/Photo Booth.app

After you've taken a photo, you can drag an image to the desktop or to a folder in the Finder to save as a jpg image.

Answer (score 4):

[ImageSnap](http://www.iharder.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/) is another great command line utility for picture taking or video recording from a connected camera (whether it's your iSight camera or a plugged-in camera). It's a handy little application.

Comment: is also available on macports

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't come pre-installed with OS X but [isightcapture](http://www.intergalactic.de/pages/iSight.html) supports command-line picture-taking with the built-in (or external) iSight.